# Flutter Marquee Text animation is affecting the Listview Builder State

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/marquee widget to apply the text animation LtR horizontally moving text on every card (as category items list) of the list but Whenever text animation applied,it is also updating the state of its parent widget list view builder and it is moving the subcategory list to index [0],How can I solve this issue ?
Here is my code :

```
 Marquee(text: controller
                                                                .trendingProductsList[
                                                            index]
                                                                .categoryUserLabel!,style:  TextStyle(
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight
                                                                    .w700,
                                                                fontFamily:
                                                                'roboto',
                                                                fontSize: 15,
                                                                color: Color(
                                                                    0xFF595959)),
                                                                blankSpace: getResponsiveSize(100.0, screenWidthFromDesignPixels, homeScreenContainerWidth),
                                                                velocity: 70.0,
                                                                pauseAfterRound: Duration(seconds: 1)




                                                            ),
```